# Launch turtlebot_world.launch failed,can't spawn turtlebot model

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ubuntu, turtlebot-gazebo, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for taking the time to watch！！

.....................

```
[ERROR] [1509691216.710669237]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
[ERROR] [1509691216.711609615]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
```

......................

```
[spawn_turtlebot_model-3] process has died [pid 6095, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base __name:=spawn_turtlebot_model __log:=/home/dclab222/.ros/log/4394944c-c05c-11e7-b25e-94de80ac314e/spawn_turtlebot_model-3.log].
log file: /home/dclab222/.ros/log/4394944c-c05c-11e7-b25e-94de80ac314e/spawn_turtlebot_model-3*.log
```

...................

When I  launch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.luanch.
It's would An error occurred.

I have reinstalled ALL ROS ,

I  can't  spawn turtlebot model, where is wrong QAQ

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274865/launch-turtlebot_world.launch-failed,can%27t-spawn-turtlebot-model/) by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2017-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be a recent issue with the gmapping nodelet.  I have the same error, here is the "fix"

https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/issues/55

I'm not sure how to actually incorporate this into my configuration in a way that helps.

---

Originally posted by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) with karma: 79 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on 2017-11-09**:
Thank you!  i'll try it ,

In fact, this error doesn't seem to affect the program?